# How to use the interval quantifier from 0 up to a specific number Regular expressions in Google Sheets?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to solve this issue:

How to use the interval quantifier curlybraces "`{}`" from `0` up to `4` in a REGEXMATCH Google Sheets formula to make it match only the occurrences from `zero` occurrence up to `4` occurrences and no more?

Here the source and context I started first from (section `Quantifiers — * + ? and {}`) [Regex tutorial — A quick cheatsheet by examples](https://medium.com/factory-mind/regex-tutorial-a-simple-cheatsheet-by-examples-649dc1c3f285)

Specifying the following:

```
a(bc){2,5}  matches a string that has a followed by 2 up to 5 copies of the sequence bc
```

My formula is:

`=REGEXMATCH($A7,"a(bc){0,4}")`

Here the 1st `input` in A7:

`abcbcbcbcbc`

Contrary to expectation, it returns `TRUE` despite `A7` having more than 4 `bc`'s as input in `A7`.

The same contrary to expectation result occurs for the following intervals `{1,4}` and `{2,4}` in :

`=REGEXMATCH($A7,"a(bc){1,4}")`

`=REGEXMATCH($A7,"a(bc){2,4}")`

It still returns matches despite 5 occurences of `bc`'s sequences in those latter two cases as well.

Here the Sheet:
[quantifier interval in regex from zero to defined interval end](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JsNDFe5QO2TbI4wskrLJhnPqAF11lf30iTmGOnInEYk/edit?usp=sharing)

I read the general regex info answer here [Learning Regular Expressions [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2759417/10789707) but couldn't find the solution.

How to make it return `FALSE` for any input of more than 4 `bc`'s in `A7`?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Try using anchors `^a(bc){2,4}$`

Comment: Thanks @The fourth bird. It works! Take care!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regex does not have to match the entire string you are checking it against by default. The function will return `True` if the regex matches any substring of the provided string.

To change that behaviour add the character `^` to match the start of the subject string and the character `$` to match its end.

For example: `=REGEXMATCH($A7,"^a(bc){0,4}$")` will not match `abcbcbcbcbc`.

Comment: Thanks @theblackips for the explanation, makes sense and it works great! Take care!